# substr() takes a vector as a string, not the values of the vector as strings

Tags: r, string, substring

I have a character vector like:

```
Variables <- c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15", "EA16", "EA19", "EA2", "EA21", "EA22", "EA24", "EA25", "EA28")
```

And `Variables` is a vector of a `df`. I want to extract from the third character in the vector above (specifically, extract the number) and I'm using this code:

```
df3["#Variable"] <- substr(df3["Variables"], start=2,stop=100)
```

However, and as you can see in the new `#Variable` vector, it takes the vector as a string, not the values of the vector as string: Why? How can I solve this?

```
   Variables       #Variable
2       EA10   c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15",
5       EA14   c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15",
6       EA15   c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15",
7       EA16   c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15",
```

Comment: Can you show a small repreoducible example and expected output

Comment: `sapply(df3["Variables"], substr, start=2,stop=100)` ?

Comment: Why is `stop = 100`? How is that related to *I want to extract from the third character in the vector above*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `df['Variables']`, you're extracting a dataframe, not a vector, and substr doesn't know how to handle it. Use either df$Variables or df[['Variables']], as I show below.

```
df <- data.frame(Variables = c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15", "EA16", "EA19", "EA2", "EA21", "EA22", "EA24", "EA25", "EA28"))
substr(df[["Variables"]], start = 2, stop = 100)
[1] "A10" "A14" "A15" "A16" "A19" "A2"  "A21" "A22" "A24" "A25" "A28"
```

Comment: Also: `with(df, substring(Variables, 2, 100))`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to extract from the third character in the vector above
>   (specifically, extract the number)

I would use `gsub()` which finds a specific pattern and replaces it.

```
Variables <- c("EA10", "EA14", "EA15")
gsub(pattern="\\D", replacement="", Variables)
#[1] "10" "14" "15"
```

- `pattern="\\D"` matches everythig that is not a digit (more [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html))
- `replacement=""` replaces it with empty space

---

As an alternative you could of course extract directly the digits, using for example `str_extract()` from the `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_extract(string = Variables, pattern = "\\d+") 
# \\d+ matches multiple digits in the string
#[1] "10" "14" "15"
```

---

Inside a `data.frame`:

```
df["Variable"] = gsub(pattern="\\D", replacement="", df["Variable"])
```

or:

```
df["Variable"] = stringr::str_extract(df["Variable"], pattern="\\d+")
```